# When would you use the UITestControl.Find method?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

When checking whether a page/screen has loaded, I often use the UITestControl.WaitForControlExist() method, but I am finding example code that follows the ctl.WaitForControlExist() with otherCtl.Find() calls on the parent controls. Like this:

```
var tab = UIMainMenuExtWindow.UIItemWindow.UIRibbonClient.UISolutionsTabPage;
tab.WaitForControlExist(3000);
UIMainMenuExtWindow.Find();
UIMainMenuExtWindow.UIItemWindow.Find();
UIMainMenuExtWindow.UIItemWindow.UIRibbonClient.Find();
UIMainMenuExtWindow.UIItemWindow.UIRibbonClient.UISolutionsTabPage.Find();
tab.Find();
Mouse.Click(tab);
```

Does this code make sense? What is the purpose of the 'Find()' calls?

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways to ask this question. What I see are MANY questions, and few if any good answers, regarding the Coded UI UITestControl.Find() method.

Answer (score 1):

After setting the `SearchProperties` and `FilterProperties` etc for a UI Control, the `Find` method causes the search to be performed. Commonly the `Find` is not called explicitly but it (or possibly some equivalent internal method) is called implicitly when the UI Control is evaluated in an expression as the parent of another control.

Consider:

```
this.uimap.uiTopLevel.ActionMethod();
```

In the above statement the value of `uiTopLevel` must be evaluated to find the object whose `ActionMethod` can be called. That evaluation requires the `Find` method.

The `Find` method may need to be called explicitly when an application replaces part of its display with another identical copy. The UI Controls, when first evaluated, get a reference to the original copy of the control. When the test tries to access the second version it may get a "control not found" or "hidden control" exception (forget the exact terminology of these exceptions). By re-evaluating the control, ie by calling the `Find` method explicitly, the new version of the control can be found.