# Coded UI waits for element to locate after page id refreshed

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, browser-automation

While writing test case in Coded UI I came across a issue. Coded UI is failing to identify some of the object that i declared after the page is refreshed, I some how managed to overcome this scenario by using **.Find()** method in Coded UI, but now Coded UI taking **10 - 20** seconds locate the element in the page. Is there any alternative way to solve this problem

```
if (strTestName != string.Empty){
    testNameFilter.Find(); 
    testNameFilter.Text = strTestName; 
 }

if (strTestDate != string.Empty){
   testDateFilter.Find();
    testDateFilter.Text = strTestDate;
}
```

Comment: can you include some details on the type of control and the search properties of each parent control?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937422/when-would-you-use-the-uitestcontrol-find-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280845/coded-ui-test-takes-2-3-minutes-to-pass and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367855/coded-ui-test-is-slow-waiting-for-ui-thread .

Comment: I Have web page in my app where i can filter result based on conditions

[Filter result page][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0xA8.png

Comment: @MichaelJamesRieger I Have web page in my app where i can filter result based on conditions
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0xA8.png
As soon as i enter value in the edit the page refreshes
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQI8s.png

and after this refresh coded ui taking 10 - 20 seconds to identify the **sampleTest** hyperlink

Comment: please post the code you are using to find the item.  if there is a wide breadth of objects to search, you want to narrow down the search at multiple levels for faster searching.  Also, if possible, please post the markup / xaml for the screen you are testing.

Comment: Please update the question instead of writing into comments.  Also, that's how you use the Find() method.